# copy-paste entire row to another sheet (need faster way)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Is there a faster way to copy an entire row from Sheets("S") to Sheets("Database")?  "S" has formulas/source.  "Database" has only values/destination.  My code is as follows, but takes too long:

```
Sub CopyPasteRow()

        Sheets("S").Rows("8:8").Copy
        With Sheets("Database").Rows(r & ":" & r)
          .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
          .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Try adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning of your macro (and turn it back to `True` at the end)

Comment: How long does it take? I used it to copy 14500 cells with different formats and formulas, and paste it on 50 rows at the same time. Took less than a second.

Comment: Also no idea where that `r` variable comes from, but it should probably be declared or at least set to something at some point.

Comment: Thank you everyone!  It took 2 seconds for the full macro, and I have to do this 700 times -- 700 x 2 = 1,400 seconds (or 23 minutes), too long!  The variable "r" is the row found in the database of 700 rows. Already turned off screenupdating, etc, Hmmm...... No faster way, guys?